# Did the apostle James the Greater travel to Spain and was he martyred in Jerusalem?

Tags: history, martyrdom, james-apostle

There are some legends that say that the apostle James the Greater (brother of John) traveled to the actual territory of Spain where he spread the Word. Also there are some accounts that place his final days in Jerusalem where he was martyred.

Is this legend true? Are there any historical accounts that support the legend? Are there any other theories about the later life of apostle James?

Comment: don't know about the historicity, but most of Spain claims St James (Sant Iago) to be their patron saint :)

Comment: In fact, that legend inspired this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not James the Greater traveled to Spain is highly contested.

The [entry on St. James the Greater in the Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08279b.htm) from newadvent.org lists some reasons why this is contested.

> With regard to the preaching of the Gospel in Spain by St. James the
>   greater, several difficulties have been raised:
>
> - St. James suffered martyrdom A.D. 44 (Acts 12:2), and, according to
>     the tradition of the early Church, he had not yet left Jerusalem at
>     this time (cf. Clement of Alexandria, Stromata VI; Apollonius, quoted 
>     by Eusebius, Church History VI.18).
> - St. Paul in his Epistle to the Romans (A.D. 58) expressed the
>     intention to visit Spain (Romans 15:24) just after he had mentioned
>     (15:20) that he did not "build upon another man's foundation."
> - The argument ex silentio: although the tradition that James founded
>     an Apostolic see in Spain was current in the year 700, no certain
>     mention of such tradition is to be found in the genuine writings of
>     early writers nor in the early councils; the first certain mention we 
>     find in the ninth century, in Notker, a monk of St. Gall (Martyrol.,
>     25 July), Walafried Strabo (Poema de XII Apost.), and others.
> - The tradition was not unanimously admitted afterwards, while
>     numerous    scholars reject it. The Bollandists however defended it
>     (see Acta    Sanctorum, July, VI and VII, where other sources are
>     given).

The fact that James the Greater was martyred in Jerusalem is pretty widely accepted since it is mentioned in the Bible.

> [**Acts 12:1-2 NIV**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2012:1-2&version=NIV)
>  
>   **1** It was about this time that King Herod arrested some who belonged to
>   the church, intending to persecute them. **2** He had James, the brother
>   of John, put to death with the sword.

Comment: It is likely that this is a tradition where a saint was adopted as a patron (like St. George for the English) and later on someone cooked up or discovered a legend connecting him to their land.